# Nexus 5 gps update rate

Tags: android, logging, gps, frequency

I have a GPS logger app I have wanted to make for a few years now. My old phone could never do it (HTC Desire Bravo A8183) as the GPS update rate was only 1Hz. Friends are telling me their Samsung and iPhones can do 5Hz GPS now. I have installed the same app I used in my HTC in my Nexus 5 to measure the GPS update rate and I am still getting 1Hz as the standard update rate from the Nexus 5.

At first all I want to make is a position recorder that saves GPS coordinates to the onboard storage. For this application power use does not matter, as using a USB car charger at the same time would make sense. It also does not matter if the 'phone' functionality of the device is impaired whilst the app is running.

My idea is to make something for personal use similar to a GoPro with inbuilt GPS logging. GPS would give you location, and distance over time gives you speed, and delta speed over time knowing weight and drag co-efficient gives you horsepower. I already know the Cd and CdA and running weight for my race car.

Anyway how do I get the phone to poll the GPS more often? Do I need to root kit the phone and then install some obscure hack? Or is it not possible?

I need accurate data in the 4-10Hz range or I may as well just forget about making this. I'm pretty sure I can buy a bluetooth GPS 'mouse' that does this but it would be much more practical to use the phones internal hardware.